# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. Source @ onClick

Tags: reactjs, onclick, render, limit

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BiAddToQueue } from 'react-icons/bi';
import { FiChevronUp, FiChevronDown, FiChevronRight } from 'react-icons/fi';
import EditArticle from './EditArticle';
import AddArticle from './AddArticle';
import { useArticleData, useData } from '../context/DashboardDataProvider';
import { getCurrentUserId } from './../services/firebaseConfig.js';
import { getFirestore, doc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const EditArticles = () => {
  const data = useData();
  const documentId = getCurrentUserId();
  const articles = useArticleData();


  const [allClose, setAllClose] = useState(false);
  const [recentClose, setRecentClose] = useState(false);
  const [articlesData, setArticlesData] = useState(articles.articlesData || []);
  const [allArticlesData, setAllArticlesData] = useState(articles.allArticlesData || []);
  const [type, setType] = useState(-1);
  const [isAddModalOpen, setIsAddModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const [articleTemp, setArticleTemp] = useState([
    {
      title: 'Article Name...',
      summary: 'Summary for the article. Edit and update as needed...',
      time: '5 min read',
      img: 'https://kiran.dev/potrate-style.png',
      link: 'https://kiran.dev/article-of-dev-ngf01...',
    },
    {
      title: 'Article line or title...',
      date: 'Feb 20, 2022',
      img: 'https://kiran.dev/potrate-style.png',
      link: 'https://kiran.dev/article-of-dev-ngf01...',
    },
  ]);

  //  ---------------- handlers -------------------------
  const handleSaveArticle = (updatedArticle, title) => {
    const updatedArticlesData = [...articlesData];
    const indexToUpdate = updatedArticlesData.findIndex((article) => article.title === title);

    if (indexToUpdate !== -1) {
      updatedArticlesData[indexToUpdate] = { ...updatedArticle };
      setArticlesData(updatedArticlesData);
    }
  };

  const handleSaveAllArticle = (updatedArticle, title) => {
    const updatedArticlesData = [...allArticlesData];
    const indexToUpdate = updatedArticlesData.findIndex((article) => article.title === title);

    if (indexToUpdate !== -1) {
      updatedArticlesData[indexToUpdate] = { ...updatedArticle };
      setAllArticlesData(updatedArticlesData);
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteArticle = (title) => {
    const updatedArticlesData = articlesData.filter((article) => article.title !== title);
    setArticlesData(updatedArticlesData);
  };

  const handleDeleteAllArticle = (title) => {
    const updatedArticlesData = allArticlesData.filter((article) => article.title !== title);
    setAllArticlesData(updatedArticlesData);
  };

  // ------------------ binary modes --------------------------------
  const openAddModal = () => {
    setIsAddModalOpen(true);
    console.log('open AddModal is called ..1️⃣')
  };

  const closeAddModal = () => {
    setIsAddModalOpen(false);
    console.log('close Modal is called ..️')
  };

  const addToArticles = () => {
    setType(0);
    openAddModal();
    console.log('Add article  is called ..')
  }
  const addToAllArticles = () => {
    setType(1);
    openAddModal();
    console.log('add All article is called ..')
  }
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setRecentClose(!recentClose)
    console.log("recent Opened..")
  }
  const handleOpen2 = () => {
    setAllClose(!allClose)
    console.log("All other Opened..")
  }


  const handleAddArticle = (article) => {
    // Use a functional update to avoid potential infinite loop
    if (type === 0) {
      setArticlesData((prevArticlesData) => [...prevArticlesData, article]);
    }
    else if (type === 1) {
      setAllArticlesData((prevArticlesData) => [...prevArticlesData, article]);
    }
    else {
      console.log("")
    }
    setType(-1);
  };


  const db = getFirestore();
  const userPortfolioRef = doc(db, 'User_portfolio_data', documentId);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updatedData = {
      ...data,
      Articles: {
        allArticlesData: [...allArticlesData],
        articlesData: [...articlesData],
      },
    };

    if (userPortfolioRef && data) {
      updateDoc(userPortfolioRef, updatedData)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Articles data updated successfully ⭕️.');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error updating Articles data:', error);
        });
    }
  }, [allArticlesData, articlesData]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className='w-screen mb-5 font-mono text-black dark:text-white flex flex-col'>
        <div className='w-full flex justify-between items-center text-white p-4'>
          <h2 className='text-xl sm:text-base px-3 py-1 flex items-center gap-1 rounded-full bg-pink-800 border border-primary font-semibold'>
            <span class='cursor-pointer'>Data</span> <span className='w-[2px] h-[80%] bg-gray-500 mx-1' /> | Edit Articles{' '}
            <FiChevronRight />
          </h2>
          <h2
            className='text-4xl mr-10 sm:mr-0 sm:text-2xl p-2  items-center gap-1 rounded-full   text-yellow-500  font-semibold'
            onClick={() => addToAllArticles()}
          >
            <BiAddToQueue />
          </h2>
          {isAddModalOpen && (
            <AddArticle
              isOpen={isAddModalOpen}
              articleData={articleTemp[type]}
              onSave={handleAddArticle}
              closeModal={closeAddModal}

            />
          )}
        </div>
        <div className='flex-grow p-4 overflow-y-auto'>
          <ul className='space-y-4'>

            <li className='bg-transparent border-2 shadow-md shadow-pink-300 border-gray-600 p-2 rounded-lg'>
              <div className='flex items-center justify-between cursor-pointer' >
                <strong className='cursor-pointer ml-1 font-extrabold' onClick={() => setAllClose(!allClose)} >All articles</strong>
                <div className='flex gap-3 text-2xl'>
                  <button onClick={()=>addToAllArticles}>
                    <BiAddToQueue />
                  </button>
                  <button className='text-pink-600 flex text-3xl font-bold hover:text-indigo-800'>
                    {allClose ? <FiChevronUp /> : <FiChevronDown />}
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              {allArticlesData && allClose && (
                <div>
                  <hr className='mb-3 mt-1 border-gray-500 border-1 dark:border-gray-700' />
                  {allArticlesData.map((article, index) => (
                    <EditArticle
                      key={`${article.title}-${index}`}
                      articleData={article}
                      onSave={handleSaveAllArticle}
                      onDelete={handleDeleteAllArticle}
                    />
                  ))}
                </div>
              )}
            </li>
            {/* <li className='bg-transparent border-2 shadow-md shadow-pink-300 border-gray-600 p-2 rounded-lg'>
              <div className='flex items-center justify-between cursor-pointer' >
                <strong className='cursor-pointer ml-1 font-extrabold' onClick={() => setRecentClose(!recentClose)} >All articles</strong>
                <div className='flex gap-3 text-2xl'>
                  <button onClick={() => addToArticles}>
                    <BiAddToQueue />
                  </button>
                  <button className='text-pink-600 flex text-3xl font-bold hover:text-indigo-800' onClick={() => setAllClose(!allClose)}>
                    {allClose ? <FiChevronUp /> : <FiChevronDown />}
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              {articlesData && recentClose && (
                <div>
                  <hr className='mb-3 mt-1 border-gray-500 border-1 dark:border-gray-700' />
                  {articlesData.map((article, index) => (
                    <EditArticle
                      key={`${article.title}-${index}2`}
                      articleData={article}
                      onSave={handleSaveArticle}
                      onDelete={handleDeleteArticle}
                    />
                  ))}
                </div>
              )}
            </li> */}
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div >
    </>
  );
};

export default EditArticles;
```

getting rerender error again again  even i used   `onClick(()=> fun())`
before it working  fine this that time addArticle was creating rerender error thta resolevd not  closeArticles  and close all article is creating eror .. but getting again

getting rerender error again again even i used `onClick(()=> fun())`

> Unhandled Runtime Error
>
> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
> Source
>
> src\components\EditArticles.js (168:98) @ onClick

```
 166 | <li className='bg-transparent border-2 shadow-md shadow-pink-300 border-gray-600 p-2 rounded-lg'>
  167 |   <div className='flex items-center justify-between cursor-pointer' >
> 168 |     <strong className='cursor-pointer ml-1 font-extrabold' onClick={() => setAllClose(!allClose)} >All articles</strong>
      |                                                                                      ^
  169 |     <div className='flex gap-3 text-2xl'>
  170 |       <button onClick={()=>addToAllArticles}>
  171 |         <BiAddToQueue />
```

I'd assume this was the right approach but maybe I am doing something wrong.
please can help to resolve this un behaviurs ?